# PagerAdapter instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) calling multiple times

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter, android-pageradapter

I have a viewPager without fragment directly inflating layouts in it,

```
 @Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    if (careersData.size() > 1) {
        if (DisplayUtil.getScreenDPI(mContext) < 320) {
            return 1.0f;
        } else {
            return 0.5f;
        }
    } else
        return 1.0f;
}
```

This is the method where I decide if I should show one or two views, When I call with single view inflating everything works as expected, but when it returns two views everything is messed up and `instentiateItem()` is calling several times, I have little-complicated layout, the parent layout is FrameLayout in XML.

I have searched so many questions but couldn't able to find any of them useful,

Here is a gist file so you can check it out: https://gist.github.com/reverseBitsTech/28610edfd455fcea6b5b98ba0e1eb0af

Comment: is your `instentiateItem()` giving you same position all the times?

Comment: same positions multi time